# Close a circuit at specific input frequency

Tags: switches, dc, frequency

I have several very simple circuits comprising of a battery connected to a LED. Additionally I have an input signal at some frequency, which I need to use in order to control these circuits. What I need is a switch for each circuit that closes it in response to a specific frequency in the input. For example, in response to a 100Hz input circuit A closes, and when switching to 120Hz circuit B closes (while A reopens).

I need it small and simple, please be gentle I'm a biologist.

Thanks!

Comment: By how much can the frequencies deviate? Is 105 Hz = 100 Hz? How about 110 Hz?

Comment: Are the input signals predefined, or would you have the option of defining the signal frequency for each control? For instance, would 30KHz and up be acceptable, with 2 KHz gaps? How many distinct such signals would you require?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading frequencies without filters](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17953/reading-frequencies-without-filters)

Comment: So, what is the purpose of this? (Just curious.)

Answer (score 1):

The NE567 PLL tone decoder ([datasheet](http://www.experimentalistsanonymous.com/diy/Datasheets/NE567.pdf)) is an IC for exactly your purpose.

The "Typical Applications" section in the data sheet gives some examples how to use it.

Comment: Note that the Philips NE567 has been [EOL](http://www.nxp.com/wcm_documents/products/eol/dn51_a.pdf)'d in February 2004, with no last time buy possible. (That was due to a fire in their Caen fab)

Comment: The LM567 from Texas Instruments is an equivalent. Also, some surplus stores have NE567 in stock, e.g. http://www.westfloridacomponents.com/IC349/NE567N+567+Tone+Decoder+Phase+Locked+Loop+IC.html has 896 in stock, at $0.61 per unit.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a lot of different frequencies, I would not do a FFT.  Instead, multiply the incoming signal by the sine and cosine of each of the frequencies you want to detect.  In other words, instead of asking what frequencies are present in the signal, you ask whether any of a specific set of frequencies is present.

I go into more detail at [Reading frequencies without filters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/17953/4512).

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest hardware, an audio ADC coupled to a DSP (such as dsPIC) running an FFT-based algorithm would be hard to beat. (I'm assuming all of the LEDs can be connected to a common decoder.)

For a more detailed answer, please provide some additional details about your situation:

- Are the input tones pure sinewaves?
- Can more than one tone be present simultaneously?
- What is the amplitude of the input tones?
- How accurately are the tone frequencies generated?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplest hardware"? Is a DSP processor (containing several thousand transistors) simpler than a NE/LM567 IC (containing ca. 5 dozens transistors)? Not to mention the complexity of the DSP software. A DSP solution might be _cheaper_ for a product sold some 10000 times, but it's not more simple.

Comment: @Curd: Two chips on a board (one chip, if the DSP has an adequate ADC built-in), with a crystal (if needed) and a bunch of decoupling caps, is really going to be about as simple as it gets for the hardware. And every DSP comes with FFT code in its library; you just need to add some logic at the output to evaluate the specific tone amplitudes. Note that I'm ignoring any hardware associated with input and output signal conditioning, which would be common to any decoder implementation.