# 256-point FFT, but only need 5-6 frequencies, is there a better way?

Tags: dsp, fourier, sampling

Due to the constraints of my system, I have a 256pt FFT.  However, I only care about the energy at 5 or 6 of the 256 bins.  256pt FFT is still faster than 5 or 6 specific DFTs, but it seems wasteful to compute 256 frequencies for only 5 or 6. Is there a better way?  Would downsampling be what I would want to do here?  If I reduce from 256 to 64 frequencies, I'd get a 5x improvement factor in the no. of operations --but I'm not sure I understand the concept fully (even after reading Oppenheim's Discrete Time signal processing" book) --ie, would this be a proper application of this concept.

Any suggestions on what to look into or further reading would be greatly appreciated, and some real world examples would help me understand is better. Thank you.

Comment: [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading frequencies without filters](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17953/reading-frequencies-without-filters)

Comment: Why would you calculate all bins if you only need a handful? Calculate the required ones only. Also consider using tables for sin and cos and when using a 32 bit platform integer calculations may suffice.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted 1 or 2 frequencies, the Goertzel algorithm would be a clear winner.

If you wanted several dozen, then the FFT would be a clear winner, even after throwing away most of the resultant samples, due to the high efficiency that factorisation of the process gives you.

With 5 or 6 frequencies required, you're in the cross-over region. It will depend on how well each algorithm is implemented. Get or write code for both, and time them.

If you understand the FFT well enough to recode parts of it, then there is a technique called 'pruning', whereby you don't calculate any of the answers you don't need. This may not save many computation cycles as a) the factorisation means that all the results will have to be calculated for the first few rounds anyway and b) conditional calculation may be less efficient than just running the loops and doing them all. Do you want to hand craft an algorithm each time you change which frequencies you want output?